# Docusign Connect Webhook Writer and Listener in .Net core

Tags: .net-core, docusignapi, webhooks, docusignconnect

I'm new to the concept of Docusign but I have successfully developed API for Envelope creation and View Url. For creating Docusign connect, I have created a Connect Configuration in the Docusign Developer Admin account. It would be a help if someone guides me on how to proceed with the Webhook Writer and Listener for the Envelope events in .Net core.I have my Event Notification object configured as well.
The other Questions mentioned related to Webhooks in StackOverflow are partial.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please check (accept) the best answer for each of your questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to our platform.

The first thing you want to do is to deploy your listener in cloud provider of your choice. We provide samples for Azure, GCP and AWS.

```
https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-listener-azure
https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-listener-aws
https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-listener-gcloud
```

Then for your worker, you want to look at the following code sample:
https://github.com/docusign/connect-csharp-worker-aws

or use related cloud provider. You will then need to update your Connect configuration with your listener endpoint.

In a nutshell, the listener will receive the events from DS Connect and queues them. The worker will pull the new events off the queue and processes them.

We have a couple videos and material coming shortly that will cover this topic in full details, so stay tuned.